# Use data received from jQuery in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, mysqli, .post

I've a comment box, i want to add a button into every comment, which will delete that comment from box when clicked. Here is how each comment is generated (just part):

```
echo '<div>'.$row['Login'].'<button id="jqhide">Hide</button></strong><br/>';
```

As you see, button has an id, when it's clicked, jquery listener start to work:

```
$("button#jqhide").click(function(){
    var smt = $(this).closest("div").find("p").html();
    $.post("send.php", smt);
});
```

in 'send.php':

```
$con = mysqli_connect(...);
$vrr = $_POST['smt'];
$sql = mysqli_query("DELETE FROM comments WHERE p_id=$vrr");
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

Here it is stuck, I mean `$_POST['smt']` seems to be empty. All I want is to delete entry from MySQL by its 'p_id'.  I'm pretty sure that I did a lot of mistakes, but that is how I try to learn something.

Addition:

I Tried to run just 'send.php' and here are errors:

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in Z:\home\localhost\www\php\send.php on line 5
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() [function.mysqli-query]: Empty query in Z:\home\localhost\www\php\send.php on line 6

send.php lines:

```
<?php 
$con = mysqli_connect(localhost, "bla", "eco", "frst_db");
$vrr = $_POST['smt'];
echo $vrr;
$sql = mysqli_query("DELETE FROM comments WHERE p_id=$vrr");
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
?>
```

Comment: You really need to make safe your code - you are going to want to protect yourself from SQL injections.

Comment: $.post expects data either in object/array format, or param format (similar to a querystring). It is unclear if you are using that format, however it appears as though you probably aren't.

Comment: However - have you checked that jQuery is actually picking up a value for $smt?

Comment: What value do you get for `smt` after that assignment?

Comment: are you sure this works: var smt = $(this).closest("div").find("p").html(); ?

Comment: If you're adding multiple buttons, they're all going to have the same ID. Look into using classes.

Comment: i've checked that in jquery, everything is ok, it should be integer by the way, i've also checked if string is token, but not, jquery takes int and send int, but it's not going

Comment: change $.post("send.php", smt); to $.post("send.php", "smt":smt);

Comment: http://i.shotnes.com/a/09/2ztg4mdo.e4r_51642aabe73de.png  <- sample

Comment: @BojanKovacevic, you surely mean passing an _object_, so `{smt:smt}`

Comment: yes,my mistake ... it is $.post("send.php", {"smt":smt}); or smt without qoutes,doesnt make difference

Comment: Bojan, it returns mistake: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

Comment: @CBroe still doesn't work

Comment: What is value of var smt = $(this).closest("div").find("p").html(); ?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld it is an integer, id of each comment

Comment: @bla2e, print here how your jquery $.post call looks now after change?

Comment: $.post("send.php", { smt: smt } );

Comment: if that is not problem, then probably smt is not found. As i said already, did you alert it just before post call?

Comment: @BojanKovacevic http://i.shotnes.com/a/09/wxpz0nm0.tn5_51642dc247a75.png

Comment: Where is that `p` element inside the `div` that you are trying to select actually?

Comment: yes, it is: http://i.shotnes.com/a/09/hcwpgk35.hlv_51642e42d2ec6.png

Comment: @bla2e what did you alert in that picture? smt? it said "gone" and you said it needs to be integer?

Comment: @BojanKovacevic sorry, i've wrote it by my own, here the right output: http://i.shotnes.com/a/09/hxna4yll.ifm_516432ec05d88.png  , it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all be careful with SQL injection

```
$sql = mysqli_query("DELETE FROM comments WHERE p_id=$vrr");
```

Now let's get back to your problem.

```
var smt = $(this).closest("div").find("p").html();
```

Where is the p tag ?

add a p tag and will work, otherwise the p tag will always be null!!!

```
<div>1<button id="jqhide">Hide</button><p>some text to be sent via ajax </p></strong><br/></div>
    <script>
        $("button#jqhide").click(function(){
            alert($(this).closest("div").find("p").html());
    var smt = $(this).closest("div").find("p").html();
    $.post("send.php", smt);
});
</script>
```

Comment: it's a bit messy, here it is: while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($show)){
 
 echo '<div id="msgBoxIn">';
 echo '<div><strong id="msgNick">'.$row['Login'].'<button id="jqhide">Hide</button></strong><br/>';
 echo "<div>".$row['message']."<br/><p id='commentId'>".$row['p_id']."</p></div></div></div><br/>";
 
}

Comment: change id="jqhide" to class="jqhide" and $("button#jqhide").click .... to $("button.jqhide").click

Comment: done, still the same, nothing deletes from box, all comments are still there

Comment: die the sql query "DELETE FROM comments WHERE p_id=$vrr", then copy manual and insert into phpmyadmin sql query textarea. And delete the box via js if you need to

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Change:

```
$.post("send.php", smt);
```

to:

```
$.post("send.php", { smt: smt } );
```